# java netty connect to multiple servers depending on packet contents

Tags: java, netty

Im looking for any kind of examples in java netty that show how you can have one incoming connection but then dependant on message content route that in a tcp proxy format to multiple servers. is that possible ?

what i am wanting to do is inspect the first part of the byte data and based on those values route to the separate servers.

hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes this should be possible. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: It is possible. Netty has plenty of documentation and examples. They even have a pass through proxy example. You could also you nginx or apache2 as proxies.